# Parallax animation running well on Chrome but slow on Safari

Tags: javascript, performance, animation

**This is the continuation of a previous question I [posted here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/129173/parallax-animation-running-well-on-chrome-but-slow-on-safari).**

I've improved (at least I think so) the initial script from the previous question, now storing the data in an array, it runs slightly better, but still sometimes there's some lag in safari. I've tried to call requestAnimationFrame on scroll and cancelAnimationFrame on scroll end, but the animation was a little jumpy so I removed that.

This is the updated code:

```
var animationId,
    parallaxElements = [];

// Push elements to array
s.parallaxElements.each(function (i) {
  var i = {
    element: $(this),
    ratio: $(this).data('parallax-ratio'),
    offset: $(this).closest('.parallax-section').offset().top - 60,
    current: 0
  };

  parallaxElements.push(i);
});

// Animation
function animation() {
  var scrollPos = s.theWindow.scrollTop();

  for (var i = 0; i < parallaxElements.length; i++) {
    var self = parallaxElements[i],
        current = self.current,
        position = current - (current - (self.offset - scrollPos) * self.ratio) * 0.1;

    if (position !== current) {
      self.element.css('transform', 'translateY(' + position + 'px)');
      self.current = position;
    }
  }

  animationId = window.requestAnimationFrame(animation);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(animation);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    parallaxElements = [];

// Push elements to array
s.parallaxElements.each(function (i) {
  var i = {
    element: $(this),
    ratio: $(this).data('parallax-ratio'),
    offset: $(this).closest('.parallax-section').offset().top - 60,
    current: 0
  };

  parallaxElements.push(i);
});
```

This looks like transforming one array to another on a 1:1 basis. This is best done with `array.map`. Also, you should cache the result of `$(this)` so that you don't call it repeatedly. Additionally, `this` inside a `jquery.each` is the current item, which should be the same as the first argument in `array.map`'s callback.

```
var parallaxElements = s.parallaxElements.get().map(element => {
  const wrappedElement = $(element);

  return {
    element: wrappedElement,
    ratio: wrappedElement.data('parallax-ratio'),
    offset: wrappedElement.closest('.parallax-section').offset().top - 60,
    current: 0
  };
});
```

Now for your animation, I suggest you avoid using `requestAnimationFrame` in this case. It will still be running even when no position changes are taking effect, eating up cycles.

Since your parallax effect only takes place only when scroll position has changed, I suggest you listen for the window's `scroll` event and do changes when scrolled. As for the movement animation, use CSS transitions.

```
$(window).scroll(event => {
  // Update element positions using transform translate
});

.parallax-element{
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}
```

Comment: May I ask what's the difference between `event => {}` and `function (event) {}`, never seen your way before.

Comment: Also `const wrappedElement = $(element);` returns an empty selector.

Comment: @ValeriuTimbuc That's arrow functions, in ES6. The empty `element`, will update answer.

Comment: Thanks, I've implement your way to create the array. I've also tried again to do it on scroll and using css transitions, but it's not the same effect, since the duration is the same regardless of how much I scrolled, I've also tried to calculate how much distance was scrolled and set the duration dynamically, but still not the same. Now I'm still using rAF, I'm trying to set a timeout on scroll so I can stop the animation after 3 seconds, but scroll is not accurate, and sometimes it stops abruptly. [Here's the code](http://pastebin.com/87WmR1uw), is there a way to have a accurate scroll event?